# @belongsToMany with @paginate

Tags: laravel, graphql, lighthouse, laravel-lighthouse

Simple models, we have a user and a user is part of topics. The linking is done through a pivot table. Both users and topics have the correct relationships. The query works. But. Now we need to add the pagination to it.

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    uuid: String!
    email: String!
    api_token: String!
    devices: [Device]

    topics(
        orderBy: _ @orderBy(
            columns: ["created_at", "last_message_at"]
        )
    ): [Topic] @belongsToMany @paginate(type: SIMPLE)

    created_at: DateTime!
    updated_at: DateTime!
}

type Topic {
    uuid: String!
    user_uuid: String!
    title: String!
    slug: String!
    key: String!
    last_message_at: DateTime!
}

extend type Query @guard {
    me: User @auth
}
```

Above the Schema, when we remove the @paginate from the user, it works without pagination. Now we need the pagination on this.

This is our GraphQL query:

```
{
  me {
    email
    topics {
      title
      last_message_at
    }
    }
  }
```

And we get the following error:

```
Node topics can only have one directive of type Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Support\\Contracts\\FieldResolver but found [@belongsToMany, @paginate].",
```

Comment: Hi peter, have you done `@belongsToMany(type:SIMPLE)` ? and remove the `@paginate`

Answer (score 0):

The directive `@belongsToMany()` have a key `type` with the `enum BelongsToManyType` and there you can use the `SIMPLE` for pagination.

Here is the directive blob [info](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/blob/master/src/Schema/Directives/BelongsToManyDirective.php).